# Upgrading from Visual studio 2012 to visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual studio 2012 ultimate installed on my PC.I would like to upgrade it to Visual studio 2013 Ultimate.

Is there a way to upgrade or Should I buy VS 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an MSDN account you can download 2013 and install it side by side with 2012, or you can remove 2012 all together and just use 2013 by itself. If you do not have an MSDN account, I believe you will need to purchase the new version. Keep in mind that if you open a solution you created with 2012 up in VS 2013, VS will attempt to upgrade the solution to work with 2013.